# How can I put multiple statements into a logical expression in a camel blueprint choice block?

Tags: apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

Inside a camel blueprint choice block we have the following:

```
<when id='foo'
    <simple><![CDATA[
        ${header.SrcSys} == 'System_A' and
        ${header.DestSys} == 'System_B'
    ]]></simple>

    <!-- do something great -->
</when>
```

I know this code is not working and also that `and` ist deprecated [since Camel 2.9](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html). But I think you know what I'm trying to do and maybe you can tell me the best way to implement such a simple expression into a camel blueprint xml.

I found [this good answer by Claus Ibsen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273050/6679645). Maybe I could use the `PredicateBuilder` inside the blueprint xml. But I try to find a solution without Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you are almost there. This works for me:

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <!-- Do not break up the following simple expression over multiple lines. It won't work. -->
        <simple>${exchangeProperty.prop1} == 'A' &amp;&amp; ${exchangeProperty.prop2} == 'B'</simple>
        <!-- Do something great... -->
    </when>
</choice>
```

The key is not to split the expression across multiple lines. I could not get this to work.

Comment: I tried to reconstruct this error with camel 2.24.2 but there the snippet in my question works fine. Maybe there was a change in camel, because I used camel 2.17.0 before. @Ralf I check your answer as accepted, because it works, but you can use line breaks in the newest camel versions.