# How to write an exists predicate for jsonpath in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, json-path-expression

In my Apache Camel application I have multiple conditions checking the existence of keys in a JSON. I want to reduce the boiler plate code, therefore I need to transform my `Expression`s to a `Predicate`.

My code with `Expression`s:

```java
.choice()
    .when().jsonpath("$.score", true).to("direct:b")
    .when().jsonpath("$.points", true).to("direct:b")
    .otherwise().to("direct:c");
```

See also: [JSONPATH](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/languages/jsonpath-language.html)

My code with `Predicate`s:

```java
.choice()
    .when(PredicateBuilder.or(jsonpath("$.score", true), jsonpath("$.points", true))).to("direct:b")
    .otherwise().to("direct:c");
```

See also: [PREDICATES](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/predicate.html)

But this is not working, because there is no `suppressExceptions` parameter (see [`BuilderSupport#jsonpath`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.22.3/org/apache/camel/builder/BuilderSupport.html#jsonpath-java.lang.String-)). Unfortunately, there is also no `exists` mehod (see [`ValueBuilder`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.22.3/org/apache/camel/builder/ValueBuilder.html)).

How can I write a `Predicate` for checking the existence of a key in a JSON?

Answer (score 1):

this code solve your problem .

```
.choice()
    .when(PredicateBuilder.and(jsonpath("$[?(@.score)]"), jsonpath("$.score"))).to("direct:b")
    .when(PredicateBuilder.and(jsonpath("$[?(@.points)]"), jsonpath("$.points"))).to("direct:b")
    .otherwise().to("direct:c");
```

Comment: Thank you, but now there are two `when`s again. My goal is to use only one `when`, because I do not want to write redundant `to`s (in my case there are some lines of code, not only one `to`). Do you know a solution? Maybe combine both with `PredicateBuilder.or`?

Comment: u can concet predicates like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/9273050/8916556